# Flutter enable multiDex for SDK less than 21

Tags: android, dart, flutter, android-multidex

How can I enable `multiDex` for SDK less than 21. 
[This page](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex) shows how to do it, but it says for API less 21.

> If you do override the Application class, change it to extend MultiDexApplication (if possible) as follows:

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication { ... }
```

So, in Flutter, my application by default overrides `io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication` and I should make changes in my `FlutterApplication` class but I couldn't open this file for editing because it is decompiled version. Can anyone help me? It is an issue on [Github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21009)

Comment: No, you just need to extend FlutterApplication and then add `@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base)
{
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}` and then specify your own application class in the androidmanifest

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I am unable to make changes in `FlutterApplication` class. it is decompiled version. So, the file is not writable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I need to create my own java class say `MyApplication.java` like this.

```
public class MyApplication extends FlutterApplication {
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

After this in `AndroidManifest.xml` file, change

```
<application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" .../>
```

to

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication" .../>
```

Comment: The only incorrect thing here was that "this is not a good solution". No, it is the correct solution.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Thank you so much, I thought I might not be, but now you say, so I am confident using it in my app.

Comment: I just hit this gotcha. Please where do I place this snippet, I mean this class?

Comment: @Wale You need to put this in your `android>app>src>main>java>package_name`

Comment: i got this error `\Application.java:15: error: package androidx.multidex does not exist
import androidx.multidex.MultiDex;` any ideas about this?

Comment: @Simou, Try to put `implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'` into `dependencies` section of build.gradle file under app folder, then import `androidx.multidex.MultiDex;` in your application class file.